# Android no title bar with action bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, titlebar

I have really tried everything I found on the internet and cannot find a solution.

I want to remove title bar from all of my activities, and my main activity to look like home activity screen on facebook. So, action bar with swiping, fragments and a search on the top. Iv done action bar with swiping and fragments right, but I cannot remove title bar for my search. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeLayout();

}

public  Lokal getLokal() {
    return lokal;
}

public Context context(){
    return getApplicationContext();
}




private void initializeLayout(){

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}
```

And here is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="v.menadzeri" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar">

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActiviy" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SplashScreen" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ProfilActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ProfilActiviy" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LokalLayoutActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LokalLayoutAct" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank you for your answer in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGmEG.png

Need the Soundboard removed, whole thing and instead of that put search box.
It doesnt allow me to put images

Comment: The title bar *is* the action bar. Please take a screenshot of what you want, upload it somewhere, and link to it from your question. If possible, annotate the drawing to indicate what you think the title bar is.

Comment: ok, how to remove it without affecting swiping and fragmetns?

Comment: Post screen of what you have and what you want. Just to make sure

Comment: Action bar tabs have been deprecated since Android 5.0. You are welcome to use another tab solution (e.g., a tabbed indicator for your `ViewPager`).

Comment: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare might interest you in this matter.

Comment: added link to picture, it doesnt allow me to add pictures yet.